# Usar o Google Youtube API V3 no Laravel 5

Tags: youtube, laravel-5, google-api

Gostaria de saber como instalar o google api v3 no Laravel 5, eu usei o composer para baixar o pacote mas não sei configurar os providers e aliases. Eu preciso para fazer um sistema que faz upload de vídeos do meu site no youtube.